# Slow query in MYSQL on production but not development

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason the following query takes 30 seconds on my production machine and less than a second locally. I've compared the char encoding, indexes etc

Any ideas?

```
SELECT ct.*, c.first_name as customer_first_name, c.last_name as customer_last_name, c.company_id as company_id 
FROM `communication_pieces` 
JOIN contact c ON c.contact_id = communication_pieces.contact_id 
JOIN customer_transactions ct ON ct.communication_piece_id = communication_pieces.id 
JOIN campaign_iterations ci ON ci.id = communication_pieces.campaign_iteration_id 
WHERE (communication_pieces.campaign_iteration_id = '1273') 
AND (communication_pieces.status NOT IN ("undeliverable","not_delivered","address_rejected")) 
ORDER BY ct.transacted_at ASC LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 0
```

One thing I noticed when doing an explain is the type in production is index for the ct table and ref in development. I know the hierarchy index is worse, but what could be the cause of the discrepancy?

Comment: How much data is returned? Where is your production machine in the network topology? What are the specs of the machine? Are other users using the production machine? Are tables locked? Too many unknowns, you're not likely to get a definitive answer from SO.

Comment: Maybe you have less data on the development machine.

Comment: Data is identical in database and both return the same number of rows.

Comment: if you are sure about number of records in both servers and also indexes, as @ColinBasnett asked, do you know the hardware specs of your Production server? does it have enough ram? also are the `Storage Engines` of the tables on both servers the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out there are differences in the way different version of MySql selects indexes to use. I was able to force the index by using rails USE INDEX syntax and get the same speed in production. Adding here in case anybody runs into a similar issue.